# Use R Shiny checkboxGroupInput to select columns for DT::dataTableOutput

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I'm pretty novice with Shiny.  I'm working on an app that connects to a database and pulls in a bunch of data, then lets the user "drill down" through a series of selectInput's and then ultimately allows them to download the results a .csv.  The download part is important.  The data is too large to let DT render it all with `server=false` so I need to maintain the filtered dataframe so that I can `write.csv()` it with my own download handler instead of the DT buttons.

The minimal example below doesn't work, but hopefully makes clear what I'm looking to do.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(magrittr)

ids <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
firstNames <- c("Bob", "Jane", "Jim", "Billy", "Siouxsie")
lastNames <- c("Smith", "Jones", "Thomas", "Idol", "Sioux")
FaveColors <- c("Blue", "Green", "Yellow", "Red", "Black")
df <- data.frame(ids, firstNames, lastNames, FaveColors)

# Define UI 
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Minimal Example"),

    # Sidebar 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            tabPanel("Columns",
                      checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "ColumnsToShow", label = "Output Columns",
                                         choices = names(df)
                      )
            )
        ),

        # Show a table
        mainPanel(
          DT::dataTableOutput("FilteredDataFrame")
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic 
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  filtered_df <- reactive({
    #THIS DOESN'T WORK :)
    temp_frame <- df %>% select(input$Columns)
    return(temp_frame)
  })

  output$FilteredDataFrame <- DT::renderDT(server=TRUE, {datatable(filtered_df(), extensions = 'Buttons',
                                                                   options = list(scrollx=TRUE,
                                                                                  lengthMenu = c(10,20,30),
                                                                                  paging = TRUE,
                                                                                  searching = TRUE,
                                                                                  fixedColumns = TRUE,
                                                                                  autoWidth = TRUE,
                                                                                  ordering = TRUE,
                                                                                  #dom = 'Bfrtip',
                                                                                  dom = 'tlip',
                                                                                  buttons = c('copy', 
                                                                                              'csv',
                                                                                              'excel')
                                                                   )
  )
  }
  )
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: You were using the wrong input element it should be `input$ColumnsToShow` and not `input$Columns` and the input should be wrapped in `all_of()` inside the `select()` function:     temp_frame <- df %>% select(all_of(input$ColumnsToShow)).  That made it work for me.

Comment: Thanks!  What a dumb mistake, though I wasn't familiar with the `all_of()` anyway.  If you'd like to post that as an answer I'll happily accept it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were using the wrong input element it should be `input$ColumnsToShow` and not `input$Columns` and the input should be wrapped in `all_of()` inside the `select()` function:

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(magrittr)

ids <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
firstNames <- c("Bob", "Jane", "Jim", "Billy", "Siouxsie")
lastNames <- c("Smith", "Jones", "Thomas", "Idol", "Sioux")
FaveColors <- c("Blue", "Green", "Yellow", "Red", "Black")
df <- data.frame(ids, firstNames, lastNames, FaveColors)

# Define UI 
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Minimal Example"),
  
  # Sidebar 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      tabPanel("Columns",
               checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "ColumnsToShow", label = "Output Columns",
                                  choices = names(df)
               )
      )
    ),
    
    # Show a table
    mainPanel(
      DT::dataTableOutput("FilteredDataFrame")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic 
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  filtered_df <- reactive({
    #THIS DOESN'T WORK :)
    temp_frame <- df %>% select(all_of(input$ColumnsToShow))
    return(temp_frame)
  })
  
  output$FilteredDataFrame <- DT::renderDT(
    server=TRUE, {
      datatable(filtered_df(), 
                extensions = 'Buttons',
                options = list(scrollx=TRUE,
                              lengthMenu = c(10,20,30),
                              paging = TRUE,
                              searching = TRUE,
                              fixedColumns = TRUE,
                              autoWidth = TRUE,
                              ordering = TRUE,
                              #dom = 'Bfrtip',
                              dom = 'tlip',
                              buttons = c('copy', 
                                          'csv',
                                          'excel')
               )
  )
  }
  )
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to select the columns *without rerendering the **DT** table*. I also move the download button linked to the download handler to the **DT** buttons.

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)


# UI
ui = fluidPage(
  downloadButton("download1", "Download iris as csv"),
  DTOutput('tbl'),
  checkboxGroupInput(
    'datacols', 
    label='Select Columns:',
    choices= c('Sepal.Length', 'Sepal.Width', 'Petal.Length', 'Petal.Width', 'Species'),
    selected = c('Sepal.Length', 'Sepal.Width', 'Petal.Length', 'Petal.Width', 'Species'),
    inline=TRUE)
  
)

# SERVER
server = function(input, output) {
  
  dat <- iris
  
  # render DT
  output$tbl = renderDT({
    datatable(dat,
              editable = "cell",
              callback = JS(
                "$('div.dwnld').append($('#download1'));",
                "var checkboxes = $('input[name=datacols]');",
                "checkboxes.each(function(index,value){",
                "  var column = table.column(index+1);",
                "  $(this).on('click', function(){",
                "    if($(this).prop('checked')){",
                "      column.visible(true);",
                "    }else{",
                "      column.visible(false);",
                "    }",
                "  });",
                "});"
              ),
              extensions = "Buttons",
              options = list(
                dom = 'B<"dwnld">frtip',
                buttons = list("copy")
              ) 
    )
    
  })
  
  
  observeEvent(input[["tbl_cell_edit"]], {
    cellinfo <- input[["tbl_cell_edit"]]
    dat <<- editData(dat, cellinfo, "tbl")
  })
  
  output$download1 <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("data-", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep="")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(dat %>% select(one_of(input$datacols)), file)
    }
  )
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```